# "Unresolved import: module" when importing a module into LiClipse

Tags: python, pycparser, liclipse

I have installed liclipse 2.4 (Python 3.0 grammar) recently and downloaded pycparser-master.zip file, extracted it, and added the pycparser-master/pycparser/ directory under Project->Properties->PyDev-PYTHONPATH->External Libraries.

I used the below import statement in my Python file.

```
import pycparser
```

But the interpreter seems to be throwing an error.

```
Unresolved import: pycparser
```

Comment: Make sure that the package you are trying to import is inside the folder you choose and not the folder itself. You might need to configurethe folder one level above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should put "pycparser-master" as the folder in the external libraries (and not pycparser-master/pycparser).

Comment: Thanks. That helped !